# The memory limit in R on Linux

Tags: r, linux

The command "memory.limit()" is used to get memory in R on windows.

What is corresponding way to get memory in R on Linux

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ulimit -v` to get memory limit for single process

Refer [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html)

Comment: "ulimit -v" is for Linux prompt. My question is for getting memory inside R script on Linux OS.

Comment: I agree. The question is about determining the machine's memory size from within R. How about it folks? Does anyone have a helpful answer?